# ReferenceError: readline is not defined, can someone help me to understand how the readline works

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
let n = parseInt(readline());
sumAndAverage(n);

function sumAndAverage(n) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    console.log(sum);
    console.log(Math.floor(sum / n));
}
```

Comment: Code examples in [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html).  Please read the doc and follow one of the examples.

Answer (score 0):

[Readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) is a module, not a global. You have to `import` or `require` it (depending on if you are writing an EJS or CJS module).

Comment: So should I write like this?

const readline = require("readline");

let n = parseInt(readline);
        sumAndAverage(n);
 
 function sumAndAverage(n) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        sum += i;
    }
    console.log(sum);
    console.log(Math.floor(sum/n));    
}

Answer (score -1):

```
var readline = require('readline');
          
var rl = readline.createInterface(
         process.stdin, process.stdout);

    
rl.question('Enter the number: ', (num) => {
    if(typeof num === 'string'){
        let int = parseInt(num)
        sumAndAverage(int)
    }else if (typeof num === 'number'){
        sumAndAverage(num)
    } else return console.log('Please enter the number.')
    rl.close();
});

function sumAndAverage(n) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    console.log(sum);
    console.log(Math.floor(sum / n));
}
```